# Printing array of strings without delimiters (brackets, quotes and commas)

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, formatting

Despite this seeming an easy task, I didn't find a satisfying way of doing it.
There are several solutions based on map or try/except but none of these seems to me solid enough (e.g. working in a general case and with 2D arrays).

This can be done with pandas, but I would like to avoid importing an entire library just for this task, is it possible to do it just with numpy functions?

To make an example of what I mean, from an array like:

```
>>a=np.vstack([['zero','one'],np.array(np.arange(2)).T]).astype('|S')

>>print a
[['zero' 'one']
['0' '1']]
```

the desired output is:

```
zero one
0 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension within `str.join()`:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in a])
zero one
0 1
```

Comment: You can drop the square brackets or use `map(' '.join, a)` for the inner part.

Comment: @AlexHall No, since the `join` method needs to preallocate the size of string it needs to generate the items once before concatenating, since list comparison is faster than generator expression within `str.join()` function.

Comment: I'm assuming that string formatting like this doesn't need to be micro-optimised.

Comment: @AlexHall Yes, but don't forget that sparks can cause huge fireworks :-)

Comment: I like this solution, straightforward, but for some reason I missed it. And I like it is a one liiner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for but a function using regular python can be made to print out the 2d array like you depicted:

```
def format_array(arr):
  for row in arr:
      for element in row:
          print(element, end=" ")
      print('')
  return arr
```

This prints:
zero one
0 1